# Scenekit orientation in IOS

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have imported a Collada file into my scene and I am using allowsCameraControl to rotate / pan the object / pan the object

I now need functionality to jump instantly to the front or side view of the object.

Does anybody know how I can get the camera that Scenekit implements in my scene and how to rotate this camera to show the front and back view ?

Answer (score 1):

"Front view" and "side view" are notions that are defined in terms of your content, so you have to define them yourself.

1. Create a node (let's call it "frontViewNode" for example) with an attached SCNCamera and position/orient it so that it's looking at whatever you call the "front" of your object. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25674762/957768) if you need help with that.
2. Create another node ("sideViewNode") that's looking at whatever you call the "side" of your object.
3. When you want to switch views, set the `pointOfView` property on the `SCNView` displaying your scene to either your "frontViewNode" or your "sideViewNode". You can even do this inside an animation (see `SCNTransaction`) to make the camera view swoop around between the two viewpoints.