# Set allowsCameraControl only in one direction

Tags: camera, rotation, scenekit, direction

I want to lock user's ability to rotate view in all directions. I need model rotation only in left and right. How can i do this?

Comment: you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654772/rotate-scncamera-node-looking-at-an-object-around-an-imaginary-sphere and adapt it to your simpler case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `.allowsCameraControl` setting to achieve this restriction. You'll have to implement it yourself, as described in [SCNCamera limit arcball rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967838/scncamera-limit-arcball-rotation).