# Set SCNNodes to have constant y-axis value?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a series of SCNPlane-type objects set to revolve around a central SCNPlane with width and height set to 0. When loading the view in my app, I get the below, which shows that my planes are being loaded correctly. Rotating them left to right with my cursor works, too. It looks like this:

[image]

However, if my cursor moves in the y-direction, the view ends up shifting so that the display is shown from another angle. Basically, the view could end up looking like this:

[image]

I don't want that to happen; I want the first image to be what I want. When I move the cursor, it should move either left or right, and not up or down.

Here is what I have tried doing:

- setting the pivot to `SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float(CGFloat(M_PI_2)), 0, 0, 0)`
- setting the rotation to `SCNVector4(1, 0, 1, Float(CGFloat(M_PI_2))`
- setting the orientation to `SCNQuaternion(0, 0, 0, Float(CGFloat(M_PI_2))`
- using the `SCNLookAtConstraint` function to center all the planes around a central coordinate and face outward
- using the `SCNTransformConstraint` function with a block that takes in the node and a matrix (`newMatrix = incomingMatrix`) variable. If it detects that the position of an object has a value of y, then `newMatrix.m42 = 0`. `newMatrix` is returned either way.

None of the above have fixed my issue. Is it even possible for me to restrict the camera to the x and z-axes only?

Comment: This sounds like you're using the built-in camera control (`SCNView` `allowsCameraControl`). Is that the case? If so, don't. Add your own camera to the scene hierarchy, and control its position directly (as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25674762/957768)). Then, when you're mapping user input to camera motion, move the node containing the camera only in the axis you want it to move in.

Comment: @rickster I found that answer you posted before I asked the question. My concern was figuring out how to implement the input. I can't find any good resources on arcball rotation _in Swift_, and I'm not sure how I'd be able to do the gesture mapping. I think the second one would be easier in my case; would you be able to expand on the explanation? The math is still confusing to me.

Comment: 1. If you're looking for help with an Apple API and you're ignoring ObjC-based resources, you're doing yourself a disservice. The most important part of the answer to any "how do I do X with SceneKit" question will be in what SceneKit APIs to call and how to architect a solution around them — language differences in the actual code are minor details. It behooves any new Swift programmer to learn to *read* ObjC (if not write it, and only well enough to grok what a program is doing and translate to Swift).

Comment: 2. There's not much math there. Put your camera on a node such that rotating the node orbits the camera, as in that answer. Then when the cursor/touch moves left, rotate the node one way, and when it moves right rotate the node the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a few days, but I finally figured out the fix.

I implemented the camera node as rickster suggested and set allowsCameraControl to false. I then implemented a UIPanGestureRecognizer and tied it to a function, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967838/scncamera-limit-arcball-rotation), which was also based on rickster's answer.

It now does what I want it to. Thanks a lot, everybody!