# How to prevent the camera from entering a SCNNode - Scenekit iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I have a problem whit the camera in SceneKit, by default i can move, rotate, zoom my camera whit this line :

```
myView.allowsCameraControl = YES;
```

But my camera can pass through walls and floor (which allows me to see the underside of the stage ) .

My first request: is it possible to apply constraints to the camera (position, rotation) ?

My second request: I thought making a cube encompassing stage and do my collision detection between my cube and my camera, but it does not work ...

code for viewDidLoad:

```
SCNView *myView = (SCNView *)self.view3D;
myView.scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"art.scnassets/Pointe Marrin 3 def 3 def 2.dae"];
myView.scene.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
myView.scene.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);
cubeLimite = [myView.scene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"Cube" recursively:YES];
camera = [myView.scene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"Caméra" recursively:YES];
cubeLimite.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic shape:nil];
cubeLimite.physicsBody.mass = 0;
cubeLimite.categoryBitMask = SCNPhysicsCollisionCategoryDefault;
cubeLimite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = SCNPhysicsCollisionCategoryAll;


//test camera
CGFloat boxSide = 0.001;
SCNBox *box = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:boxSide
                            height:boxSide
                            length:boxSide
                     chamferRadius:0];
SCNNode *boxNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:box];
SCNPhysicsShape *shape = [SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry:boxNode.geometry options:nil];
camera.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic shape:shape];
camera.physicsBody.mass = 0;
camera.categoryBitMask = SCNPhysicsCollisionCategoryDefault;
camera.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = SCNPhysicsCollisionCategoryAll;
```

Code for delegate :

```
- (void)physicsWorld:(SCNPhysicsWorld *)world
 didBeginContact:(SCNPhysicsContact *)contact{
NSLog(@"Contact debut");
}
- (void)physicsWorld:(SCNPhysicsWorld *)world
 didUpdateContact:(SCNPhysicsContact *)contact{
NSLog(@"Contact milieu");
}
- (void)physicsWorld:(SCNPhysicsWorld *)world didEndContact:(SCNPhysicsContact *)contact{
NSLog(@"Contact fin");
}
```

The delegate :
    SCNPhysicsContactDelegate
is declared in the .h file

Ideas ?
thank you beforehand

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, as far as I know, to constrain the default camera when `allowsCameraControl` is enabled.

The answer to [Rotate SCNCamera node looking at an object around an imaginary sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654772/rotate-scncamera-node-looking-at-an-object-around-an-imaginary-sphere?newreg=d73e07e4144348f3bbbd3df1ac85da26) outlines an approach that might work for you, depending on what constraints you need to build.