# ARKit: How can I add a UIView to ARKit Scene?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, arkit

I am working on an AR project using ARKit.

I want to add a UIView to ARKit Scene. When I tap on an object, I want to get information as a "pop-up" next to the object. This information is in a UIView.

Is it possible to add this UIView to ARKit Scene?
I set up this UIView as a scene and what can I do then? 
Can I give it a node and then add it to the ARKit Scene? If so, how it works?

Or is there another way?

Thank you!

EDIT: Code of my SecondViewController

```
class InformationViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var secondView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view = secondView
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Code in firstViewController

```
guard let secondViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController else {
    print ("No secondController")
    return
}

let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(0.1), height: CGFloat(0.1))       
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = secondViewController.view

let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
```

I only get a white screen of a plane, not the view.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the information to be displayed in 3D, in the real world? Or that you want the information to be displayed with a segue to another view controller?

Comment: I want to place it in 3D in the real world.

Comment: As Lësha mentioned above that works very nicely up until iOS 12.1.x
Afterwards, what ends up happening, if you need to ever dismiss the UIViewController that presents the UIViews inside of a SCNPlane, the top two thirds of your screen will become unresponsive to touch down events. Submitted this bug earlier today.

Comment: @TeodorIuliuRadu did you find out more meanwhile? I'm on 12.2 beta and recogniser don't work at all for me ._.

Comment: it's now this easy https://stackoverflow.com/a/74380559/294884

Answer (score 19):

The simplest (although undocumented) way to achieve that is to set a `UIView` backed by a view controller as diffuse contents of a material on a `SCNPlane` (or any other geometry really, but it works best with planes for obvious reasons).

```
let plane = SCNPlane()
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = someViewController.view
let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
```

You will have to persist the view controller somewhere otherwise it's going to be released and plane will not be visible. Using just a `UIView` without any `UIViewController` will throw an error.

The best thing about it is that it keeps all of the gestures and practically works just as a simple view. For example, if you use `UITableViewController`'s view you will be able to scroll it right inside a scene.

I haven't tested it on iOS 10 and lower, but it's been working on iOS 11 so far. Works both in plain SceneKit scenes and with ARKit.

Comment: didnt knew about it. I have to try this

Comment: If I call the secondView I only get a white screen, I posted the code of my secondViewController above.

Comment: @Informatics You shouldn’t reassign `self.view` in `viewDidLoad()`. If you instantiate `InformationViewController` from storyboard and it has `secondView` there, the `view` will contain it.

Comment: Ok, I changed it, but I have the problem, that I only get a white screen without content.

Comment: @Informatics do you initialize view controller using UIStoryboard?

Comment: Yes:   
            guard let secondViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController
                else {
                    print ("No secondController")
                    return}

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you so much!
By the way, I also had the problem of only seeing a white plane, but that was because I wasn't storing a reference to the view controller anywhere. I declared a variable inside the main view controller to keep a reference to the secondary view controller and now it works, it even scrolls (I used a table view controller to test the interaction).

Comment: Please can you explain with more details because I created let vc = SecondVC() In the main controller not inside the method but only I see a white screen

Comment: that is an extremely interesting observation.. however for me it doesn't seem that UITapGestureRecognizers inside the view work, do the? also normal touches seem to be ignored.. any idea? .-.

Comment: @LëshaTurkowski This doesn't seem to work anymore. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446393/arkit-uiview-setanimationsenabled-performing-any-operation-from-a-background and here: https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/in-chapter-11-i-get-an-error-when-a-qrcode-is-detected/76973

Comment: it works perfectly https://stackoverflow.com/a/74380559/294884  You must use the LAYER though.  it's that easy.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot provide you code now but this is how to do it.

1. Create a `SCNPlane`.
2. Create your `UIView` with all elements you need.
3. Create image context from `UIView`.
4. Use this image as material for `SCNPlane`.

Or even easier make `SKScene` with label and add it as material for `SCNPlane`.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74380559/294884

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I create an image context from UIView?

Comment: I am sorry i cant give you anything now. You can find creating image from uiview easily on stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks a lot! My problem is now that I cant call the view.  It doesn´t work with the ViewController.

Comment: Have you used/watched twitter ar app? This method is similar (thats what i think). You can just display UIView as material for plane. And have other nodes(plane) as buttons. You can change UIView's elements with tap on nodes used as buttons and change the material for plane.

Comment: And I think Lësha Turkowski's method is what you need.

Comment: @AlokSubedi when I created UIView to image and applied but button clicks not working. how to get event for inside the UIView ?

Comment: @YogendraGirase button will not work because it is just an image not a functional UIView. You can just pass UIView with button instead of converting it to image like Lesha's answer, but it was not stable in my case. Seems it is still buggy. So what I did was add a UIView on SCNNode as image and used hittest to fake button tapped.

Answer (score 1):

To place text in a label in the world you draw it into an image and then attach that image to a `SCNNode`.

For example:

```
let text = "Hello, Stack Overflow."
let font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: CGFloat(size))
let width = 128
let height = 128

let fontAttrs: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = 
[NSAttributedStringKey.font: font as UIFont]

let stringSize = self.text.size(withAttributes: fontAttrs)
let rect = CGRect(x: CGFloat((width / 2.0) - (stringSize.width/2.0)),
                  y: CGFloat((height / 2.0) - (stringSize.height/2.0)),
                  width: CGFloat(stringSize.width),
                  height: CGFloat(stringSize.height))

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)))
let image = renderer.image { context in

    let color = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(CGFloat(0.5))

    color.setFill()
    context.fill(rect)

    text.draw(with: rect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: fontAttrs, context: nil)
}

let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(0.1), height: CGFloat(0.1))
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = image

let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
```

EDIT:
I added these lines:

```
let color = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(CGFloat(0.5))

color.setFill()
context.fill(rect)
```

This lets you set the background color and the opacity. There are other ways of doing this - which also let you draw complex shapes - but this is the easiest for basic color.

EDIT 2: Added reference to `stringSize` and `rect`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine!!! Do you know, how I can change the background color and the opacity?

Comment: Yep - I just added in the three lines you will need in order to draw the background color.

Comment: Hey there, where does your code get the `rect` variable from?

Comment: @Cesare I added this in now. The `rect` is the bounding box that you want to draw into within the image. `x`, `y` is the top left corner.

Comment: @Jordan thanks, this code is not displaying anything on my end.

Comment: @Jordan when I created UIView to image and applied but button clicks not working. how to get event for inside the UIView ?

Comment: This method turns the view into an image for display. This is the most robust if you want it to look correct - but you lose all the functionality of the view (so you won't be able to tap on internal buttons). If you still want it to be an actual UIView you will need one of the answers provided above, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712156/7098234