# Error - Expressions are not allowed at the top level

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, scenekit, arkit

I am having some trouble running this code, I found it on another `Stack Overflow` post. [ARKit: How can I add a UIView to ARKit Scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48700939/arkit-how-can-i-add-a-uiview-to-arkit-scene)
Would like to see if it works for me. But I can't figure out why there is the error "**Expressions are not allowed at the top level**".

```
let text = "Hello, Stack Overflow."
let font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: CGFloat(12))
let width = 128
let height = 128

let fontAttrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] =
        [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font as! UIFont]

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(width), 
height: CGFloat(height)))
let image = renderer.image { context in

    let color = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(CGFloat(0.5))

    color.setFill()
    context.fill(CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
            size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size))

    text.draw(with: (CGRect( origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: 
    UIScreen.main.bounds.size)), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: 
            fontAttrs, context: nil)
}

let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(0.1), height: CGFloat(0.1))
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = image
let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
```

The error "Expressions are not allowed at the top level" 
is found on the line of code that says:

```
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = image
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to move all this code into a function e.g func generateText() {} and then call it in viewDidLoad :)