# Add Customized UIView to Scenekit's node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit, scenekit

I am beginner in Scenekit development, I am trying to add UIView as diffuse content of SCNPlane node but getting some weird crash.

Code:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = SCNScene()
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.1, height: 0.1)
        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = getCustomView()
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        planeNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
        sceneView.scene = scene
    }

    func getCustomView() -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }
```

Crash :

[image]

I am trying to achieve following output with designing UIView

[image]

[image]

Please let me know how I can add UIView as SCNNode's diffuse content.

Answer (score 2):

Use this extension to get the image representation from the UIView

```
public extension UIView {
 @available(iOS 10.0, *)
 var image: UIImage {
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
    return renderer.image { rendererContext in
        layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
    }
  }
}
```

And call it on your custom View like the following :

```
getCustomView().image
```

And finally on your SCNNode's Plane like the following :

```
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = getCustomView().image
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing Legos and K'Nex here.

Let's go to the documentation and see what is a valid diffuse content for SCNMaterial:

> You can set a value for this property using any of the following
>   types:
>
> A color (NSColor/UIColor or CGColor), specifying a uniform color for
>   the material’s surface
>
> A number (NSNumber), specifying a uniform scalar value for the
>   material's surface (useful for physically based properties such as
>   metalness)
>
> An image (NSImage/UIImage or CGImage), specifying a texture to be
>   mapped across the material’s surface
>
> An NSString or NSURL object specifying the location of an image file
>
> A video player (AVPlayer) or live video capture preview
>   (AVCaptureDevice, in iOS only)
>
> A Core Animation layer (CALayer)
>
> A texture (SKTexture, MDLTexture, MTLTexture, or GLKTextureInfo)
>
> A SpriteKit scene (SKScene)
>
> A specially formatted image or array of six images, specifying the
>   faces of a cube map
>
> When you examine elements of a scene loaded from a file, this value is
>   always either a color object (of the NSColor or UIColor class,
>   according to platform) or an image object (of the NSImage or UIImage
>   class, according to platform). You can therefore use type
>   introspection (the isKind(of:) method in Objective-C, or the is
>   operator or let-as matching in Swift) to determine the type of the
>   material property’s contents.
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents

Let us look at what UIView is:

> class UIView : UIResponder
>   class UIResponder : NSObject
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder

As you can see,  UIView is not a valid type.

However,  UIView does contain a `CALayer`

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622436-layer

So you should be able to use that to get what you need from your view:

```
func getCustomViewLayer() -> CALayer {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    return view.layer
}
```

Comment: Thanks @knightOfDragon I will check and get back to u

Comment: @knightOfDragon it's giving me same crash

Comment: Looks like something else is crashing , does it crash when your contents is nil?

Comment: It's crashing when I am setting scene to sceneView's scene

Comment: I am not familiar with scene kit, but something is pointing to nil that shouldnt be nil it looks like

Comment: I don't know nothing is nil when I debug it. added screenshot of it.

Comment: do this code in view will appear, not view did load.  I have a feeling something is not prepared on apples side

Comment: For 2022 .. I'm afraid the code presented is completely wrong, and will do nothing!  The view in question has to persist inside something in UIKit (even though the CALayer gets moved).  The simple hello world example in the answer I typed in, works perfectly, just use an IBOutlet and the rather tricky bringup sequence will work.

Comment: That is just flat out wrong.  The view does not need to persist in anything, and all that matters is the layer is extracted out of it.  The only thing that matters is that layer is somehow retained, which is something beyond the scope of the question.  Documents do not list contents as a weak reference.

Answer (score 0):

### To put a UIView on a SCNNode:

Superficially, it's very simple.

```
@IBOutlet var anyUIView: UIView!
```

and then ...

### You have to use the *layer* ...

```
func test() {
  somePictureNode.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = anyUIView.layer
}
```

It's that easy.

It's very difficult to get good quality though, and drawing order and layout can be strange.

### Re-warning ... !

Just to repeat, you will find the layout EXTREMELY strange moving from UIKit to SceneKit! You CAN use the constraint layout engine if you are truly on your toes! My guess is that in a couple yrs (say, by 2025) Apple will put some time in to rationalize the UIKit-like layout engine in SceneKit.  Keeping track of / making layout happen is also hell!  But for simple UIView, you are all set.