# Is there a way to render Views as Entities in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, view, uiview, augmented-reality, realitykit

I've been trying to find a way to display UIViews as 3d objects in my ARView. I have been trying to create a sort-of a box which would act as a display to contain a UIView but with no luck.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712156/7133103) provides a solution for SceneKit, but the same does not seem to work in RealityKit.
My idea so far was the following, but couldn't find a way to actually hook up a UIView.

```
let box = MeshResource.generateBox(width: 0.6, height: 0.3, depth: 0.02, cornerRadius: 0.03)
let material = SimpleMaterial()
material.baseColor =  --SET UIVIEW AS DIFFUSE OF MATERIAL?--
let entity  = ModelEntity(mesh: box, materials: [material])
anchorEntity.addChild(entity)
```

Answer (score 2):

I see the following solution: You can use `snapshotView()` or `snapshot()` instance methods to get a snapshot of a contents of a current UIView (and then you must convert it to `.jpg` and the use it as a texture for 3D model) or to get a snapshot as `.hdr` (and then convert it to `.jpg` as well).

```
arView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
```

or:

```
arView.snapshot(saveToHDR: true, completion: { (image) in ... } )
```

An approach showing you how to apply a texture on a RealityKit's **box primitive**:

```
@IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    arView.environment.background = .color(.systemGray2)
    let scene = try! Experience.loadBox()
    
    var material = SimpleMaterial()
    material.baseColor = try! .texture(.load(named: "snapshot.jpg"))
    
    let mesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.3)

    let model = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
    model.position.x = 0.3
    model.setParent(scene)

    arView.scene.anchors.append(scene)
}
```

Also, take into consideration that RealityKit 2.0 supports video-textures thru [VideoMaterial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/videomaterial).