# ARKit -[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:] Performing any operation from a background thread on UIView or a subclass is not supported

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, grand-central-dispatch, arkit

I have a ViewController that has a collectionView inside of it. I display the contents of the collectionView's cells inside an ARSCNView.

When I set the ViewController's view property to the Material's `content property` I get the error from the question.

```
material.diffuse.contents = self.myViewController.view // produces error and sometimes it crashes. When it does't crash I can see the collectionView fine but the error is still there
```

I know it's the vc's `view property` that is causing the problem because when I try to set the vc without using its view property the error goes away. The thing is I can no longer see the vc on the Scene.

```
material.diffuse.contents = self.myViewController // produces no error but the collectionView is no longer visible.
```

**How I can set the vc's view property on the mainQueue to avoid this problem?**

The [same problem happened](https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/in-chapter-11-i-get-an-error-when-a-qrcode-is-detected/76973) to this person.

My code (other then the delegate methods this is all the code inside the class):

```
MyViewController: UIViewController, ...CollectionViewDataSource && Delegate {

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        // create collectionView
    }()

    var dataSource = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4" ...]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

            self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
            // set its anchors
        }
    }
}
```

ClassWithSceneKit:

```
lazy var sceneView: ARSCNView = { ... }()

let myVC = MyViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.main.async  {

        self.myVC.tableData.append("9")
        self.myVC.tableData.append("10")
        self.myVC.tableData.append("11")
        self.myVC.collectionView.reloadData()

        self.myVC.view.isOpaque = false // the background is clear, look in the picture I attached

        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = self.myVC.view // ** this is the line causing the problem ***

        let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.5, height: 0.7)
        plane.materials = [material]
        plane.cornerRadius = 0.015

        let node = SCNNode()
        node.geometry = plane
        node.position = SCNVector3(0.36, 0.12, -0.8)

        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    }
}
```

> ARKit_4[20429:4746699] [Animation] +[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:]
>   being called from a background thread. Performing any operation from a
>   background thread on UIView or a subclass is not supported and may
>   result in unexpected and insidious behavior.

```
trace=(
    0   UIKitCore                           0x000000019a855fa4 B7E79AF1-F09F-3BCE-B073-ECEA027BC0E8 + 15241124
    1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103356bd8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001033584c8 _dispatch_once_callout + 84
    3   UIKitCore                           0x000000019a855f08 B7E79AF1-F09F-3BCE-B073-ECEA027BC0E8 + 15240968
    4   UIKitCore                           0x000000019a856090 B7E79AF1-F09F-3BCE-B073-ECEA027BC0E8 + 15241360
    5   UIKitCore                           0x0000000199b9d030 B7E79AF1-F09F-3BCE-B073-ECEA027BC0E8 + 1900592
    6   UIKitCore                           0x000000019a5fdd0c B7E79AF1-F09F-3BCE-B073-ECEA027BC0E8 + 12782860
    7   UIKitCore                           0x000000019a40462c B7E79AF1-F09F-3BCE-B073-ECEA027BC0E8 + 10712620
    8   UIKitCore                           0x000000019a5fbaa4 B7E79AF1-F09F-3BCE-B073-ECEA027BC0E8 + 12774052
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000019a401b8c B7E79AF1-F09F-3BCE-B073-ECEA027BC0E8 + 10701708
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000019a4029ac B7E79AF1-F09F-3BCE-B073-ECEA027BC0E8 + 10705324
    11  UIKitCore                           0x000000019a402710 B7E79AF1-F09F-3BCE-B073-ECEA027BC0E8 + 10704656
    12  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa496864 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 2283620
    13  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa4969c8 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 2283976
    14  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa4b67d8 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 2414552
    15  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa329168 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 786792
    16  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa2f94c8 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 591048
    17  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa2f93f0 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 590832
    18  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa31c0f0 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 733424
    19  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa31935c 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 721756
    20  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa31809c 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 716956
    21  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa31700c 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 712716
    22  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa43f878 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 1927288
    23  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa43f5cc 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 1926604
    24  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa44684c 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 1955916
    25  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa2d2554 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 431444
    26  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa2d3ea4 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 437924
    27  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa3cbe28 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 1453608
    28  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa3cc694 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 1455764
    29  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa3ccc00 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 1457152
    30  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa3ccf94 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 1458068
    31  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa4672f0 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 2089712
    32  ARKit                               0x00000001b176d104 4003283E-C369-3DBD-A6D1-3D04690F6674 + 958724
    33  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa32d8d0 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 805072
    34  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa432b1c 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 1874716
    35  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103356bd8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    36  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103365858 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 124
    37  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa432aac 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 1874604
    38  GPUToolsCore                        0x000000010357d5f8 -[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 168
    39  QuartzCore                          0x000000019cc72860 8705A7FE-6FD6-301F-BE30-D32F13CB6C0E + 71776
    40  IOKit                               0x00000001972a4930 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 488
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001962ba670 FF63481D-FB6A-353B-B2C1-AC4EAECF594D + 525936
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001962e3e40 FF63481D-FB6A-353B-B2C1-AC4EAECF594D + 695872
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001962e356c FF63481D-FB6A-353B-B2C1-AC4EAECF594D + 693612
    44  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001962de440 FF63481D-FB6A-353B-B2C1-AC4EAECF594D + 672832
    45  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001962dd8a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
    46  Foundation                          0x000000019661d824 3C682044-3249-3938-8111-F2F12D066D2B + 30756
    47  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa32dcac 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 806060
    48  SceneKit                            0x00000001aa32def4 5DCB330E-65B4-3BA3-8648-D7BB0F7849CC + 806644
    49  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001960821d0 _pthread_start + 124
    50  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000196085ae0 thread_start + 8
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Apple and they said this feature currently isn't supported. They sent me the info under a nda so I can't elaborate beyond that.

They did say if it was a feature I wanted I can send a request to their team to see if they would consider adding it.

Comment: How do you mean ? So we can't use UIViews in Arkit anymore ?

Comment: No not regular uiviews, as of the time I contacted them you can’t use collectionViews or tableViews In ARKit.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, how do you do so for regular custom views ? I tried setting it as  material diffuse contents value but noticed corner radius wasn't applied to it as well as I couldn't see the subview within it.

Comment: Ask a new question and add some code. I’ll take a look at it. Send me the link here when you’re done.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62286757/set-uiview-as-scnmaterial-content thanks the link, let me know you thoughts

Comment: Gimme like an hour so, I’m in the middle of something but I’ll help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue by using `view.layer` instead of `view` according to [Playing GIF using GIFU library in SceneKit causes app UI freeze any solution? UIView Animated being called from a background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507447):

```
material.diffuse.contents = self.myVC.view.layer
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your answer before and it doesn’t work. Thanks for trying though

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar issue when I wrapped SwiftUI `view` to `HostingViewController` and passed it to `SCNNode.material.diffuse.contents`. The problem was, that in iOS15 onwards, only the very first *snapshot* of the view was displayed - no animations, no interaction.

I tried many workarounds like rendering `view` to `Image` 30 times per second and passing it to `SCNNode`, but nothing has worked.

I ended up with computing perspective transformation matrix and applying `CATransform3D` on the `view`.

Works like a charm now.