# Set UIView as SCNMaterial content

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm trying to use a UIView with Arkit 3D space. I've seen a few examples which requires the UIView or UIView's layer is set as the diffuse content of the SCNMaterial object. That's not working as I've expected so far. I only see the frame of the view but the subviews within it are not added neither is a corner radius on the layer visible.

```
func setupBillBoard() {
    let view = PlayerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 40))
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 14

    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = view.asImage()
    material.isDoubleSided = true

    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
    plane.materials = [material]

    let node = SCNNode()
    node.geometry = plane
    node.position = SCNVector3(box.x, box.y + 0.3, box.z - 0.4)
    node.scale = SCNVector3(0.4, 0.4, 0.4)

    self.billBoardNode = node
}
```

View Extension to convert UIView to image capture

```
    extension UIView {
        func asImage() -> UIImage {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
            return renderer.image { rendererContext in
                layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
            }
        }
    }
```

So far I get only a red square shaped view in the scene and nothing more

Custom class code here: https://www.paste.org/106551
Xib in attached image

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to call view.layouIfNeeded() after you create the view. As I look at your code and mines below that's the only difference that I see. Otherwise it looks fine. If you have any problems I'll post the code to GitHub, you can just load it in your project and run it. Let me know.

Comment: debugging currently, haven't had luck yet with my custom UIView

Comment: I can see the red view with a rounded corner, perhaps its the way my custom UIView is created

Comment: Three things. First did you call view.layoutIfNeeded() after creating your UIView? Second what's PlayerView? Maybe there is something inside that subclass that is causing the problem. Third try changing PlayerView to UIView and see what happens and then switch back over to PlayerView.

Comment: If PlayerView isn't confidential add the code from that to your question also.

Comment: OK! I've now resolved it thanks largely part to adding view.layoutIfNeed() as well as in my init function of the custom view to add the container view as a subview. I posted a linkto the PlayerView in the question above https://www.paste.org/106551

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the way i set mines up and it works fine. You should be able to copy and paste the function inside `viewDidLoad` and you will see a red circle. You can also use an `UIImageView` instead of a `UIView`.

After you create you custom `UIView` call `yourView.layoutIfNeeded()` before adding it to the `SCNMaterial`.

You can also set the corner radius on a geometry: `plane.cornerRadius = 0.015` like I did in `createAndPositionGrayNode()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createAndPositionRedCircleNode()

    // or try it with an imageView, comment out the line above
    // createAndPositionGrayNode()
}

func createAndPositionRedCircleNode() {

    let redImage = UIColor.red.imageRepresentation

    let myView = UIView()
    myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 250)
    myView.layer.contents = redImage.cgImage
    myView.layoutIfNeeded() // <-- myView.layoutIfNeeded() called here
    myView.layer.contentsGravity = CALayerContentsGravity.resizeAspectFill
    myView.layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    myView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    myView.layer.cornerRadius = myView.frame.width / 2

    let convertedImage = myView.asImage()

    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = convertedImage

    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.15, height: 0.15)
    plane.materials = [material]
    plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true

    let redNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    redNode.name = "redNode"
    redNode.position = SCNVector3(0.0, 0.2, -0.7)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(redNode)
}

func createAndPositionGrayNode() {

    let lightGrayImage = UIColor.lightGray.imageRepresentation

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 250)
    imageView.image = lightGrayImage
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.backgroundColor = .clear
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = imageView.image

    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.4, height: 0.4)
    plane.materials = [material]
    plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    plane.cornerRadius = 0.015 // <-- geometry cornerRadius set here

    let grayNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    grayNode.name = "grayNode"
    grayNode.position = SCNVector3(0.0, 0.2, -0.7)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(grayNode)
}

extension UIView {
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
            return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lance, this really helped

Comment: will sure do, thank you very much mate. Happy Coding

Comment: Really nice... Thank you both.