# ARKit – Get current position of ARCamera in a scene

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm in the process of learning both ARKit and Scenekit concurrently, and it's been a bit of a challenge.

With a ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration session created, I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to get the position of the user's 'camera' in the scene session. The idea is I want to animate an object towards the user's current position.

```
let reaperScene = SCNScene(named: "reaper.dae")!
let reaperNode = reaperScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "reaper", recursively: true)!
reaperNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -1)
let scene = SCNScene()
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(reaperNode)

// some unknown amount of time later   
let currentCameraPosition = sceneView.pointOfView?.position
let moveAction = SCNAction.move(to: currentCameraPosition!, duration: 1.0)
reaperNode.runAction(moveAction)
```

However, it seems that currentCameraPosition is always [0,0,0], even though I am moving the camera around. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Eventually the idea is I would rotate the object around an invisible sphere until it is in front of the camera and then animate it in, doing something similar to this: [Rotate SCNCamera node looking at an object around an imaginary sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654772/rotate-scncamera-node-looking-at-an-object-around-an-imaginary-sphere) (that way the user sees the object animate towards them)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Set yourself as the `ARSession.delegate`. Than you can implement `session(_:didUpdate:)` which will give you an `ARFrame` for every frame processed in your session. The frame has an `camera` property that holds information on the cameras transform, rotation and position.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    // Do something with the new transform
    let currentTransform = frame.camera.transform
    doSomething(with: currentTransform)
}
```

---

As [rickster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957768/rickster) pointed out you always can get the current `ARFrame` and the camera position through it by calling `session.currentFrame`.
This is useful if you need the position just once, eg to move a node where the camera has been but you should use the `delegate` method if you want to get updates on the camera's position.

Comment: This works, but you can also get frames without being the session delegate by getting the session's `currentFrame` property.

Comment: @rickster you are tight and I have edited the answer, but usually you want to have other nodes react to you changing your position, eg by following you around. Then you would want constant updates on new camera poses anyway.

Comment: True. Point is, depending on how your app is otherwise set up, you could either have ARKit delivering you frames at 60 fps and you rendering as you get them, or you could be running your own render loop at (up to) 60 fps and ask ARKit for a frame each time you need one. It supports both ways, so use whichever you like.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help! I'm using frame.camera.transform.columns.3.x ... any reason why that shouldn't work? I'm not clear on what the difference between the columns are, but 3 seems to do it for me.

Comment: This is not working consistently for me. I'm frequently getting (0,0,0) as xyz coordinates.

Comment: Check the [`trackingState`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera.trackingstate) of the camera, maybe you are moving to fast for the camera

Comment: I get "[DeviceMotion] Event ref invalid" whenever I run an ARSCNView.session. Anyone have an idea why I get this?

Comment: Based on @rickster 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45084187/arkit-get-current-position-of-camera-in-scene/51972161#comment77162624_45089244) How can this be made? I need the frames position for a rate of 25 fps

Comment: How would you get the camera position from transform?

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same result if the tracking configuration is: ARImageTrackingConfiguration? In my case ARCamera is always in position 0,0,0!

Comment: Does anyone know what all the values in the transform matrix are? They are very hard to figure out.

Answer (score 13):

I know it had been solved but i have a little neat solution for it .. 
I would prefere adding a renderer delegate method.. it's a method in ARSCNViewDelegate

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, willRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {
    guard let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView else { return }
    let transform = pointOfView.transform
    let orientation = SCNVector3(-transform.m31, -transform.m32, transform.m33)
    let location = SCNVector3(transform.m41, transform.m42, transform.m43)
    let currentPositionOfCamera = orientation + location
    print(currentPositionOfCamera)
}
```

of course you can't by default add the two SCNVector3 out of the box.. so you need to paste out of the class the following

```
func +(lhv:SCNVector3, rhv:SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
     return SCNVector3(lhv.x + rhv.x, lhv.y + rhv.y, lhv.z + rhv.z)
}
```

Comment: Why are you just taking the diagonal entries of the rotation matrix? And why is "position" equal to "orientation + location". The position is the location, i.e. the last column of the transform. The upper left 3x3 matrix contains the orientation (and possibly scale and shear). There exist different methods to extract pitch, yaw and roll from it, but the diagonal is not one of them.

Comment: @kjyv where did you see the location is the last column of the transform? thanks for sharing!

Comment: The transformation matrix is a 4x4 matrix, hence homogenous coordinates. The documentation might not explicitly say this but it is pretty standard. Have a look e.g. here for the 2D case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations

Comment: @kjyv is `transform.m33` for `orientation` supposed to be `-transform.m33`?

Comment: For orientation it's probably better to just use sceneView.pointOfView.presentation.worldOrientation.
If you really need to get it from the transform, have a look e.g. here https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50963/how-to-extract-euler-angles-from-transformation-matrix
You should prefer a quaternion over ambiguous euler angles.

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels - the transform's orientation is contained in a 3x3 matrix, not just the diagonal entries. The position is the location

Comment: Can someone explain why "position = orientation + location"? What does adding the orientation here do exactly? I was under the impression that the position should just be the location?

Answer (score 7):

### ARKit + SceneKit

For your convenience you can create a `ViewController` extension with an instance method `session(_:didUpdate:)` where an update will be occured.

```
import ARKit
import SceneKit

extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        let transform = frame.camera.transform
        let position = transform.columns.3
        print(position.x, position.y, position.z)     // UPDATING        
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        sceneView.session.delegate = self             // ARSESSION DELEGATE

        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(config)
    }
}
```

### RealityKit

In RealityKit, ARView's object contains a camera's transform as well:

```
import RealityKit
import UIKit
import Combine

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    var subs: [AnyCancellable] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arView.scene.subscribe(to: SceneEvents.Update.self) { _ in            
            let camTransform = self.arView.cameraTransform.matrix
            print(camTransform)                             // UPDATING  
        }.store(in: &subs)
    }
}
```