# ARKit – Position of the ARCamera

Tags: 3d, camera, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm trying to use ARKit and my question is very simple. How can I get the position of the camera?

I know that if I put a `SCNNode` on (`0`,`0`,`0`) and my ARCamera is looking on the ground for example, I will have to look up to see the 3D Object. That's mean that somehow the position and the orientation of the camera of the device must be accessible.

So how do I know `where the camera is` and `where she is looking to`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARKit - Get current position of 'camera' in scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45084187/arkit-get-current-position-of-camera-in-scene)

Comment: That partially answer my question. I understand what the camera transform is, but i don't know how to use it to change the coordinates of my SCNode.
Can you explain to me ? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `ARCamera.transform` property to get the current transform of your camera. 
The following code is from [Introducing ARKit at WWDC 2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/602/?time=1307) which you probably want to watch as an introduction.
We are using the transform to place a node 10 cm in front of the camera.

In Swift:

```
var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
translation.columns.3.z = -0.1 // Translate 10 cm in front of the camera
node.simdTransform = matrix_multiply(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
```

In Objective-C

```
matrix_float4x4 translation = matrix_identity_float4x4;
translation.columns[3][2] = -0.1; // Translate 10 cm in front of the camera
node.simdTransform = matrix_multiply(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
```

Comment: That's what I call a true hero ! Thanks a lot ! 
And if I want to offset the x and y coordinates it's on the 3rd column too ?

Comment: You should read and learn some basics in 3d graphics and [transformation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Examples_in_3D_computer_graphics)

Comment: can you replicate in Objective c ?

Comment: @Dev_Tandel It would be something like this:
```
matrix_float4x4 translation = matrix_identity_float4x4;
        translation.columns[3][2] = -0.1; // Translate 10 cm in front of the camera
        node.simdTransform = matrix_multiply(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation);
```

Comment: @orangenkopf - Thank you i converted your other answer

Comment: Hi @jlsiewert! I am wondering whether you could help me with this Scenekit related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63023016/swift-correct-the-arfaceanchor-from-left-handed-to-right-handed-coordinate-syst

Comment: Hey @jlsiewert, thank you so much for your detailed answers! I and my team stuck on an issue for days ah :/ I posted an interesting question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662318/arkit-apply-filter-cifilter-to-a-specific-part-vertex-of-an-arfaceanchor Would love your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the following approach for `X`, `Y` and `Z` axes simultaneously:

```swift
var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4

translation.columns.3 = simd_float4(0, 0.2, -0.5, 1)      // x, y, z, w

aNode.simdTransform = matrix_multiply(translation, 
                                      currentFrame.camera.transform)
```

The last element in the `columns.3` is the **homogeneous coordinate** (`w`), it's equal to `1`.