# Not getting session `didUpdate` for camera position in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm new to swift, and I'm trying to get the location of the camera in the ARKit example, but it's giving me `nil`.

I used the solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45084187/arkit-get-current-position-of-camera-in-scene) and set the delegate to `self`, but it's still not giving me the camera transform.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sceneView.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        print("Hello")     // DOES NOT RUN HERE
        let currentTransform = frame.camera.transform
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is it? Are you getting `nil` for the transform as stated in your question, or is the `session:didUpdate` function not being called at all, as stated in your code?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. `session:didUpdate` is not being called at all. I tried accessing transform property in the `viewDidLoad` and got `nil` then figure the camera probably hasn't been initialized. Title has been updated.

Answer (score 16):

Simple fix, first your class definition:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate
```

Then you'll need to set yourself as the delegate like so:

```
sceneView.session.delegate = self
```

And then everything's going to work just right.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use an `extension` for `ViewController`, so you can add there a protocol `ARSessionDelegate` which `ViewController` conforms to:

```
extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

        let transform = session.currentFrame.camera.transform 
        print(transform)                              // NOW IT WORKS        
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sceneView.delegate = self                     // ARSCNVIEW DELEGATE
        sceneView.session.delegate = self             // ARSESSION DELEGATE
    }   
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }
}
```