# How to get coordinates of a SCNNode in respect to the Device Reference?

Tags: objective-c, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I wonder how to get the coordinates of a SCNNode in respect to the `Device Reference` (and not in respect to the `World Reference`)?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARKit - Get current position of 'camera' in scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45084187/arkit-get-current-position-of-camera-in-scene)

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to get the position of the `ARCamera` node. You could do this by looping through all the child nodes until you find the ARCamera (or possibly using the ARSCNView's `pointOfView` method, not sure about this one).

Once you find the camera you can store it into a `SCNNode` type variable, then you would basically need to get the difference in positions between the two. You could do something like:

```
SCNVector3Make(cameraNode.x - targetNode.x, 
               cameraNode.y - targetNode.y, 
               cameraNode.z - targetNode.z);
```